# Send multiple URIs with adb am

Tags: android, adb, activity-manager

I'm trying to simulate my activity being started with the intent `android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE`. To do this I need to pass in the extra "android.intent.extra.STREAM" with an array of uris (strings). I'm trying to start this from the shell using the `am` command. However, it appears that I can't specify a Uri/String list as an extra using `am`. The only array type extras I see are for ints, longs, and floats.

Is there a different way to simulate sending multiple Uris from the shell?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of all Android command line tools - only basic data types are supported as parameters. Which is very unfortunate because it is very easy to add command line support for the already existing XML Serialization used internally.